# Button in UICollectionViewCell is not working

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionviewcell

I am using UICollectionView for first time. I have a button in my UICollectionViewCell. I am using the segues to connect the button with next view controller to be loaded on button tap event.

The button loads next view controller only for first button in the list of collection view cells. For other buttons it seems like it is not receiving the touch event.

Any idea?

Comment: can you share some code ??

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem: Either create multiple prototype cells and wire the IBAction of each button, or register the button action when the cell is created.  One way to do that would be to grab the button in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method, and do the following:

```
for (UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            switch (indexPath.item) {
                case 0:
                    UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)view;
                    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    UIButton *myOtherButton = (UIButton *)view;
                    [myOtherButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myOtherAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

etc.